# Label with custom font and text with binding doesn't work

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a `Label` with `Font` set to an icons font (font awesome) which has the `Text` bound like this:

```
<Label Text='{Binding Icon}'>
  <Label.FontFamily>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
        <OnPlatform.iOS></OnPlatform.iOS>
        <OnPlatform.Android>icons.ttf#Icons</OnPlatform.Android>
    </OnPlatform>
 </Label.FontFamily>
</Label>
```

it doesn't render the icon, it renders the Unicode value `&#xf032;` instead.

It works if I set the text without binding, like this:

```
<Label Text='&#xf032;'>
```

I suspect there's some kind of race condition between setting the text and the font.

I need the binding, but I don't know any workarounds.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Return the escape sequence of `\uf032` from your binding instead of instead of `&#xf032;`

Comment: Woooow... Thanks! Can I ask what's the issue? Why does it work with the escape sequence but not with my string?

Comment: It seems the &#xf032; escape sequence only works for XAML and the \uf032 only works for binding when using Xamarin.Forms 4.5.530 +  currently.

Comment: It doesn't work for me :-(
Visual Studio 2022, Xamarin Forms 5.0.0.2244

Answer (score 0):

SushiHangover's works in my case but if you're using *Font Awesome Material Design Icons* (referenced in my XAML as `materialdesignicons.ttf#Material Design Icons`) or any Unicode character that exceeds 0xFFFF, you need to use a syntax like this:

```
"\U000F09D7"
```