# Xamarin MVVM Custom Font Not Working In Data Template

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, fonts, bind

Having trouble with using a font. Works fine when I to the following down below.

```
FontFamily="{StaticResource IconFonts}" Text="&#xf139;"
```

But it doesn't work if I try to dynamically bind the text property.

```
FontFamily="{StaticResource IconFonts}" Text="{Binding Comments}"
```

It shows up all weird. It looks like it tries to do something but doesn't completely render. Here is the full code with my testing included down below. Thanks in advance.

```
<FlexLayout x:Name="FlexFood"
        Wrap="Wrap"
        Direction="Row"
        JustifyContent="Start"
        Padding="0, 10"
        BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding FoodCollection}">
<BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackLayout Padding="5, 0">

                    <Frame.GestureRecognizers>

                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnTypesSelected"></TapGestureRecognizer>

                    </Frame.GestureRecognizers>

                    <Frame.Content>
                        <StackLayout x:Name="LayoutFood">

                            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                                <Label x:Name="LabelTitle" Padding="0, 10">
                                <Label.FormattedText>
                                    <FormattedString>
                                        <Span FontSize="Subtitle" Text="{Binding Title}" FontAttributes="Bold"></Span>
                                        <Span Text=" "></Span>
                                        <Span FontSize="Subtitle" Text="{Binding Version}" FontAttributes="Bold"></Span>
                                    </FormattedString>
                                </Label.FormattedText>
                            </Label>
                            </StackLayout>

                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">

                            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">

                                <Label Text="{Binding Description}" FontSize="Body"></Label>-->
                                <Label FontSize="Caption" TextColor="#LELELE">
                                    <Label.FormattedText>
                                        <FormattedString>
                                            <Span Text="{Binding fDepartment}"></Span>
                                            <Span Text="{Binding pType}"></Span>
                                        </FormattedString>
                                    </Label.FormattedText>
                                </Label>

                            </StackLayout>

                            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="End">

                            <Label Text="{Binding Comments}"></Label>

                            <Label FontFamily="{StaticResource IconFonts}" Text="&#xf139;"></Label>

                            <Label x:Name="LabelTypeTest" FontFamily="{StaticResource IconFonts}"
                                    Text="{Binding Comments, StringFormat='&#xf123;'}"></Label>

                            <Label FontFamily="{StaticResource IconFonts}" Text="{Binding Comments}"></Label>

                            <Image x:Name="ImageTypeTest">
                                <Image.Source>
                                    <FontImageSource Size="48" FontFamily="{StaticResource IconFonts}" Color="#000000"></FontImageSource>
                                </Image.Source>
                            </Image>

                            </StackLayout>

                            </StackLayout>

                        </StackLayout>
                    </Frame.Content>

            </helper:LayoutGradient>
        </StackLayout>
    </DataTemplate>
</BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
</FlexLayout>
```

Here is the static resource in app

```
<ResourceDictionary>

    <OnPlatform x:Key="IconFonts" x:TypeArguments="x:String">

        <On Platform="iOS" Value="Material Design Icons"></On>

        <On Platform="Android" Value="IconFonts.ttf#Material Design Icons"></On>

        <On Platform="UWP" Value="/Assets/IconFonts.ttf#Material Design Icons"></On>

    </OnPlatform>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue, but I am wondering about "Material Design Icons" value. That does not seem like a valid font family name, I don't think there should be spaces? Also, is this issue occurring on all platforms?

Comment: Oh, if these are font icons, did you set them as per this document? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/fonts#display-font-icons , IOW it looks like they should be used in an Image, not a label

Comment: Can you please share us a Minimal, Reproducible Example with the font resources? I can't reproduce it on my side.

Comment: i followed the instructions on a tutorial. Will try to find the source link. Ok will try out the image versus a label and that you mention it, it works on other area but I have to check to see if they are all under an image.

Comment: Ok, I will check once you share the source link:).

Comment: Here is the source link https://montemagno.com/using-font-icons-in-xamarin-forms-goodbye-images-hello-fonts/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return the escape sequence of `\uf139` from your binding instead of `&#xf139`;

You can read the Access from Bindings and Access Directly in XAML section in the source link for more information.

Refer: [xamarin-forms-fontawesome-doesnt-work-with-bound-properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53990920/xamarin-forms-fontawesome-doesnt-work-with-bound-properties)

Comment: I've tried either and it still doesn't show the correct icon. I'm gonna go back to the drawing board with the original source I used to see where I'm messing up at https://montemagno.com/using-font-icons-in-xamarin-forms-goodbye-images-hello-fonts/

Comment: Well, it should work with \uf139 and I will test it later.

Comment: Couldn't figure out what I did wrong but I re did everything and it work thanks all