# Binding Unicode from JSON to XAML via C# not working. Is there a way?

Tags: c#, json, xaml, binding, font-awesome

## Intro

I want to use the same Font Awesome 5 icons in the mobile app as I do on a website.

The following XAML snippet shows the icon perfectly.

```xml
<!-- Events.xaml -->

<Label Text="&#xf51c;" FontFamily="{StaticResource FA-Solid}" />
```

I wish to bind the data received from JSON to the `Text` value for this icon.

The problem is that I can't convert Font Awesome code to a working Unicode in C#, and sending the Unicode directly adds a backslash before the code in JSON. Note that the letter `č` is correctly converted to it's Unicode equivalent in JSON. But how do I send the actual icon to JSON for it to convert it to the correct Unicode?

## Creating JSON [PHP]

```php
# api.php

$data = fetch_database_table_into_associative_array(); // Function made up for explanation
/*
[
  0 => [
    'title' => 'Tečaj',
    'icon' => 'f51c',
  ],
  1 => [ ... ],
  ...
]
*/

die(json_encode(['events' => $data]));
/*
{
   "events":[
      {
         "title":"Te\u010daj",
         "icon":"f51c"
      },
      {
         ...
      },
      ...
   ]
}
*/
```

## Receiving and converting response [C#]

Fetching data asynchronously with `HttpClient.GetAsync`, reading it to string and deserializing to  my object works perfectly well.

`Event` is

```c
public class Event
{
  [JsonProperty("title")]
  public string Title { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("icon")]
  public string Icon { get; set; }
}
```

and collection of all events is `List<Event> Events` with data filled.

## Attempt 1

```xml
<!-- Events.xaml -->

<Label Text="{Binding Icon}" FontFamily="{StaticResource FA-Solid}" />
```

This (obviously) renders text `f51c`.

## Attempt 2

```xml
<!-- Events.xaml -->

<Label Text="&#x{Binding Icon};" FontFamily="{StaticResource FA-Solid}" />
```

This fails to bind anything.

## Attempt 3

Added property FormattedIcon to model Event and tried

```cs
// Events.cs

foreach (var Event in Events)
{
  Event.FormattedIcon = "&#x" + Event.Icon + ";";
}
```

```xml
<!-- Events.xaml -->

<Label Text="{Binding FormattedIcon}" FontFamily="{StaticResource FA-Solid}" />
```

This renders Unicode (I think without the ending `;`) instead of icon.

## Attempt 4

After reading that `&#x...;` format is for XAML and `\u...` for code-behind on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45506122/9583480) I changed the statement from inside the `foreach` loop (Attempt 3)

```cs
// Events.cs

foreach (var Event in Events)
{
  Event.FormattedIcon = "\u" + Event.Icon;
}
```

This causes an error and does not compile.

## Attempt 5

Same as above but tried to escape the backslash.

```cs
// Events.cs

foreach (var Event in Events)
{
  Event.FormattedIcon = "\\u" + Event.Icon;
}
```

Renders the Unicode again (in different format than Attempt 3).

## Attempt 6 & 7

Went back to JSON creation in PHP and replaced `'icon' => 'f51c'` with `'icon' => '\uf51c'` as well as `'icon' => "\uf51c"`, and in both cases `json_encode` converted the icon string into `\\uf51c` ie. backslash was added before string.

So lastly I tried to remove just the first backslash in code-behind with

```cs
// Events.cs

foreach (var Event in Events)
{
  Event.FormattedIcon = Event.Icon.Substring(1);
}
```

but it just removed the escaped backslash and rendered `uf51c`;

## Attempt 8

Changed JSON data back to just `'icon' => 'f51c'`. Changed `string FormattedIcon` to `char FormattedIcon` in model `Event`. Tried to read string as Unicode character.

```cs
// Events.cs

foreach (var Event in Events)
{
  int characterCode = Convert.ToInt32(Event.Icon);
  Event.FormattedIcon = (char)characterCode;
}
```

Error with converting

## Attempt 9

Changed `char FormattedIcon` back to `string FormattedIcon` in model `Event` as per [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56019210/9583480).

```cs
// Events.cs

foreach (var Event in Events)
{
  int characterCode = int.Parse(Event.Icon, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
  Event.FormattedIcon = Char.ConvertFromUtf32(characterCode);
}
```

Error with converting (`System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'`)

## Help

Any suggestions on lucky number 10 ?

Comment: Use [base64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tobase64string?view=net-5.0) encode/decode.

Comment: Try to create a static class with constant value such as `public const string Adjust = "\uf042";` and try to use it like this `<TextBlock Text="{x:Static local:FontAwesomeIcons.Adjust}" FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesome}"/>`. Is this work?

Comment: @Max Thank you for pointing in some direction. I tried converting my Unicode into base64 in PHP, but on `json_encode()` the `\xXX\xYY\xZZ` got converted into `\\xXX\\xYY\\xZZ` so it was about as useful as before. I would love to get a proper answer, but for the time being I just used a plain `switch` statement, for the limited number of used cases (4).

Comment: You must use only base64 without json, encode on base64 -> send -> decode base64.

Comment: Thanks again, but sadly specs demand JSON.